# HTML5 Input Types & Touch Device Keyboards: Appropriate Number, Tel & Text Usage?

Tags: html, keyboard, numbers, html-input, tel

I would like to automatically initiate the numeric keyboard on touch devices for zip code and social security number input fields.  Zip codes are entered in a five digit format, while SSNs are entered as 111-22-3333.  My understanding is that type=number and type=tel fields will automatically initiate the appropriate keyboard, so these inputs seem appropriate, but I'm not confident they are the right choice.

**Type=Number**

I originally thought type=number would be the optimal solution (since it sounds semantically correct), but have since found that this type is really only for true numbers and not strings of numeric characters.  I've seen blog posts making accusations of browsers automatically including the comma as a thousands separator, and stripping leading zeros on submission (neither of which are zip/ssn friendly).

**Type=Tel**

From what I have read, this seems like the best solution to my problem.  I'm concerned by the meaning of this new type though.  Should I really be using a telephone field for zip code and ssn?  What if some mobile phone manufacturer decides to start showing the address book for tel fields?  That would make no sense for a zip or ssn.

**Alternatives**

I've found that the new pattern attribute of type=text inputs can be used to trigger the numeric keyboard on iOS devices, but that only partially solves the problem.

I've also found a new attribute [inputMode](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#attr-fe-inputmode) which seems to be the ideal solution, but doesn't seem to be implemented by any browsers yet.

**The Question**

What I'm hoping is that someone has a suggestion or a best practice?  Should I use TEL?  Should I go with the iOS solution and ignore other devices?  Will inputMode ever work?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use pattern and inputMode only. 
Additionally, Type = number is acceptable if you are only accepting integers between 0-999 and you are okay with the extra validation that will be done - even if the user clicks cancel.

Type=Number has issues even if it is a number, let alone a SSN etc, as it has unpredictable handling of values with regard to negative numbers, localization, precision, leading zeroes, etc, depending on the browser's implementation. Best practice is to avoid unless you have an internal website with a fixed user base where you know the devices/locales being used - unless you are expecting an integer between 0 and 999. Negative numbers, decimals, and thousand characters all will have problems on certain devices.
In addition, if you use 'type' the page will validate data even if the user clicks a cancel button.  You could globally turn off validation, but now the page will auto-delete any invalid data on post back! If either of these are acceptable to you, you can use 'type'.

Type=Tel works 'today' but as you point out, it is dangerous to use as who knows what browsers will do in the future.  Not to mention that '122-222-2223 Ext.34' isn't even accepted by these devices. I would advise caution if it is a phone number, and avoidance otherwise.  The day may come that some device decides to validate the number even though the HTML5 specs say not to.

Pattern=... is good to add. Most browsers will ignore it, so use another validator as well, but at least newer iOS devices will use it, and that's 45% of mobile users.

InputMode=... seems to be the only other hope at this time. Hopefully it will get supported in the future.